# what is the level of include function covers in php?

Tags: php

i am using include function. I want to know the level of using it. coming to the point, I have a page called hitcounter.php where i want to know how many hits were made to that page in my application. So i created hitcounter.php

My problem is i included this hitcounter.php in one of my page where i want to know the hits of that particular and store it in db. In hitcounter.php i include dbconnection.php.When i logged in into my application and i hit that particular page where i include hitcounter.php it is giving error no database selected.

Out of all my 2.8 years of experience i got this error for the first time i google a lot but i didnt find the answer for this.

My hitcountercode:

```
include"dbconnection.php";
//Adds one to the counter 
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET patient_dashboard = patient_dashboard + 1")or die (mysql_error());

//Retreives the current count 
$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT patient_dashboard FROM counter"))or die(mysql_error());

//Displays the count on your site
 print "$count[0]";
```

This is how i include hit counter.php

```
<?php include"../includes/subpageheader.php";
      include"../includes/hitcounter.php"; 
?>
```

mydatabase connection code:

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
//echo $conn."<br/>";
$db=mysql_select_db('health');
```

i want to know upto how many levels we use include function in php.
So, how to solve this error can anyone please help me.

Comment: You haven't provided any code related to the actual connection to the database.

Comment: @ramsai see my answer, you should be including from the root and not from the current directory. Regards

Answer (score 1):

**Include**

Explaination on `INCLUDE` from the php documentation found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

You could clean up your includes by using the `root directory` with the [$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) function and [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function, then create a path to the file. For example...

```
<?php
$my_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$subpageheaderphp = $my_root . "/direct/path/to/file/from/root/subpageheader.php";
if(file_exists($subpageheaderphp)){include $subpageheaderphp;}else{echo "subpageheader in directory $subpageheaderphp could not be found <br/>";}
$hitcounterphp = $my_root . "/direct/path/to/file/from/root/hitcounter.php";
if(file_exists($hitcounterphp)){include $hitcounterphp;}else{echo "hitcounterphp in directory $hitcounterphp could not be found <br/>";}
```

PHP example... Below is the file structure I will be using for my stimulation of including another file.

[image: File structure]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/0rq4g0tc.e0r.png))</sub>

Contents of **IncludeFrom.php**

```
<?php
$DownStructure = "../../../includeTo.php";
echo "Including from the current directory: ".$DownStructure."<br/>";
if(file_exists($DownStructure)){include $DownStructure;}
$UpStructure = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/start/includeTo.php";
echo "<Br/>Including from first directory: ".$UpStructure."<br/>";
if(file_exists($DownStructure)){include $UpStructure;}
```

Contents of **includeTo.php**

```
<?php echo "<b>IncludeTo.php</b> was included!!"; ?>
```

PHP results

[image: results]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/tv4cumnu.xn3.png))</sub>

The benefits to this is, it is much easier to track and navigate to files in your folder structure. By doing this you will be including from the base of the application, which will not require you to *navigation down levels* but instead *up levels* through your site folder structure. Although either solution is fine. The difference between `$DownStructure` and `$UpStructure` is that, `$DownStructure` is a relative path whereas `$UpStructure` is absolute.

**Database not selected error**

A very easy solution to your database not being selected would be. To update your `queries` to include the database for example `SELECT * FROM mydatabase.mytable WHERE column = 'value'` or in *php syntax* `SELECT * FROM $database.$table`, where `$database` and `$table` are storing the necessary information about where you wish to go.

In the example below, I am inserting several values into the table `Address` with the `SalesLT` database selected.

> INSERT INTO SalesLT.Address
>           (AddressLine1, City, StateProvince, CountryRegion, PostalCode)
>   VALUES ('75 W. 66th Street','New York','NY','United States','10023')

Address table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
`AddressLine1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`City` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`StateProvince` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`CountryRegion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`PostalCode` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

PhpMyAdmin Results. I have not selected a `primary database` to use, but my query has selected its `database` for the `insert query`.

[image: phpmyadmin]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/emyog4u5.lrd.png))</sub>

Php test with the following code, You'll notice in the example below I never select a `database` with [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Address"));
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo"</pre>";
phpinfo();
?>
```

Results...

[image: php test]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/ihnd52op.qf4.png))</sub>

The benefits to including the `database` in your queries, is you can do cross server queries. And as long as you're connected to the `database` *your queries will go where you specify*. This is much more efficient than selecting a `primary database` with the [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) function in php.

Comment: @ramsai I have extended my answer with screen shots to represent results with code. I hope this answers your question. Regards

Comment: Thank you very much KILLrawr you gave a great explanation and i am going through it.

Comment: :) no problem, I'm glad I could help, if my answer is sufficient I would appreciate if you selected it as the final answer. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your error has nothing to do with include, the problem is that you are not selecting a database, look at this example:

```
 <?php

 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
 if (!$link) {
 die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
 }

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
 die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```