# PHP isn't writing to file

Tags: php, io

I'm making a registration form, but can't seem to write to text file. In this code, I'm putting a person's real name in their file in acc/pplid/[name].txt The file isn't writing at all - the echo doesn't output anything. I'm running off of Microsoft Webmatrix on my computer. Thanks in advance!

```
        $irlname = $_POST["irlname"];
        $name = $_POST["username"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $name = htmlentities($name);

        echo $name;
        file_put_contents("acc/pplid/".name.".txt", $irlname);
        echo file_get_contents("acc/pplid/".$name.".txt");
```

Comment: FYI, this allows you to overwrite arbitrary files by putting a NUL byte in the name and using `../` to go up in the directory tree. It also makes no sense to HTML-escape a filename. Files that cannot be written to can be read - so the code is double bad.

Comment: I'm sorry that my code is double-bad. I've escaped the filename because it's a textbox on the other end, no checking of any kind. If you'd like to tell me how I could prevent NUL bytes, that would be helpful. My top concern is making it work. :P Thanks, though. I'll look into it.

Comment: The only safe thing for such a case (besides using a database instead of flat files) is using a strict whitelist to validate the string

Comment: I've made NUL bytes be replaced with nothing, and it now makes sure that it only contains a-z and 0-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_put_contents("acc/pplid/".name.".txt", $irlname);
```

Should be

```
file_put_contents("acc/pplid/".$name.".txt", $irlname);
```

unless `name` is defined else where, otherwise I'd say check the write permissions. Check the status of the **folder** with [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) or [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) prior to `file_put_contents`.

**Example**

```
if(is_dir("acc/pplid") && is_writable("acc/pplid")){
    file_put_contents("acc/pplid/".$name.".txt", $irlname);
} else echo "A problem with the folder occurred";
```

Comment: I'll check if file_exists, as adding the $ didn't fix it

Comment: I added `print( file_exists("acc/pplid/") );` as well as `print( file_exists("acc/pplid/".$name.".txt") );` and the page is simply blank. When I check the properties of the folder, the tick box for it is filled, like it if some files are read-only and some aren't. When I untick it and re-open the properties window, it still is filled.

Comment: "What do you mean? this folder could not be found" was outputted

Comment: "A problem with the folder occurred"

Comment: Read this answer I gave on file management for php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289705/what-is-the-level-of-include-function-covers-in-php